# HTTPS certificates for load balancing gRPC traffic

Tags: https, load-balancing, grpc, traefik

Why [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/grpc/) v1.6 requires to have HTTPS certificates on both gRPC Server and Traefik?

Comment: I do not agree with your guys that it's off-topic, my question was not related to configuration things, but more about a concept.  Because, based on the documentation I required to have an SSL cert, but I was not able to find a reason to do so. Now I know that it was due to Go lang limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Golang only support HTTP2 over HTTPS.

In the next Træfik release (1.7) you will be able to use H2C (HTTP2 without HTTPS) https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/user-guide/grpc/